# SEDE text-only output column width is not correct for datetime columns

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

The column width of `date`, `time`, and `datetime` typed columns in text-only output mode is too narrow. [The following query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/681866?opt.textResults=true):

```sql
select 
  'a' a,
  'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' b,
  getdate() c,
  'a' ddd,
  'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' e,
  3 f,
  3 fff,
  3 g
```

Produces this text-only output:

```
a b                            c             ddd e                            f fff g 
- ---------------------------- ------------- --- ---------------------------- - --- - 
a aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 2017-06-06 23:42:27a   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 3 3   3
```

Note that column `c` is only given a width of 13 characters when it should be at least 19, and that values in that column butt up against the next column with no whitespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a bug in how the column width for Date types is determined for textonly results.

I have added the following code to the SEDE codebase to resolve the issue.

```
if (_nativeTypes.Contains(resultSet.Columns[i].Type))
{
    // Date is formatted later for textresults!
    if (col != null && resultSet.Columns[i].Type == ResultColumnType.Date)
    {
        // col contains a long 
        // for textresults it is formatted later
        // instead of taking its length
        // use the length that will come out after
        // the String.Format is applied
        curLength = DATE_COLUMN_WIDTH; 
    }
    else
    {
        curLength = col?.ToString().Length ?? 4;
    }
}
```

When I run this locally, this is my result:

[image]

The pull request is [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/82). Allow for 6 to 8 weeks for Nick to merge and re-deploy.